# Annotation @URL. How to parameterize

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation

I use @URL from package org.hibernate.validator.constraints;
How I can to parameterize this annotation?
I can make so url valid using parameters:
`google.com`  ?

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` annotation has a number of parameters

```
String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL.message}";
Class<?>[] groups() default { };
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
String protocol() default "";
String host() default "";
int port() default -1;
@OverridesAttribute(constraint = Pattern.class, name = "regexp") String regexp() default ".*";
@OverridesAttribute(constraint = Pattern.class, name = "flags") Pattern.Flag[] flags() default { };
```

You can see them [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.html).

When using it, just add the parameter values you want. The parameters without a `default` value are required (there aren't any in this case).

```
public class MyClass {
    @URL(message = "Some message stating that something is wrong", port = 1234 /*, add more */)
    private String exampleHostUrl;
}
```